# How to install RGtk2 on OS X 10.10.5?

Tags: macos, homebrew, r

I am trying to install RGtk2. I have installed GTK+ and XQuartz with Homebrew:

```
$ brew cask install xquartz 
Warning: A Cask for xquartz is already installed. Add the "--force" option to force re-install.
$ brew install gtk
Warning: gtk+-2.24.28_2 already installed
```

But when I try installing it I get the error

```
Rgtk.c:7:10: fatal error: 'gdk/gdkx.h' file not found
```

Have I missed installing some necessary package?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like a problem with RGtk2 which does not support Quartz GTK on OS X (and provided by Homebrew). I followed the advice posted here:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/43290

Which suggests installing the binary version:

```
install.packages("RGtk2", dependencies = T, type = 'mac.binary.mavericks')
```

Comment: I just had the same problem and your answer helped. The funny thing, though, is that your link was to an issue that *I* opened back in August. Guess I forgot what I learned! Ha! Thanks again.

Comment: This does not work on macOS Sierra:
`package ‘RGtk2’ is not available (as a binary package for R version 3.4.0)`